# MongoDb combine Text Search with other queries (using $or)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

Using the Mongo C# driver (1.10) I'm attempting to write a query that combines a text search with some other filters. Note: The query executes if I replace the **OR** with **AND**.

```
    public IEnumerable<Asset> GetAssets(AssetSearch search)
    {
        var list = new List<IMongoQuery>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Text))
        {
            list.Add(Query.Or(
                Query.Text(search.Text), 
                Query<Asset>.Matches(a => a.FileName, search.Text)
            ));
        }

        if (search.FolderId.HasValue)
            list.Add(Query<Asset>.EQ(a => a.FolderId, search.FolderId.Value));

        return AssetCollection.Find(Query.And(list));
    }
```

I get this error when execute with (search.Text = "football")

```
"QueryFailure flag was Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=db.assets limit=0 skip=0 Tree: $and $or filename regex /football/ TEXT : query=football, language=, tag=NULL folderId == ObjectId('55d72ad19b958b1e7c0506ff') Sort: {} Proj: {} No query solutions (response was { "$err" : "Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=db.assets limit=0 skip=0\nTree: $and\n $or\n filename regex /football/\n TEXT : query=football, language=, tag=NULL\n folderId == ObjectId('55d72ad19b958b1e7c0506ff')\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n No query solutions", "code" : 17007 })."
```

Comment: No doubt the BSON interpretation with "AND" ignores the condition altogether as all query arguments in MongoDB queries are implicitly an "AND" condition anyway. The problem is that an `$or` abstracts from the top level of the BSON document, and a `$text` search operation cannot be used other than at the top level only. So not inside the implied structure of `{ "$or"": [ { "$text": { "$search": "term" } }] }`. This has to do with index selection as with the way "text search" is performed, it does not make sense to "mix" results in output that is ordered by relevance with an external condition

Comment: _$text search operation cannot be used other than at the top level only_ -- Didn't know this. So I suppose I will need to write 2 separate queries and combine the results? I really like the features of the text search... but I also need to retrieve results like **football**.jpg which only seems possible using $match.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Text filter but it doesn't work for me. So anyone wants to search in multiple columns with single query. You can try this.

```
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Or(
    Builders<Book>.Filter.Where(p=>p.Title.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower())),
    Builders<Book>.Filter.Where(p => p.Publisher.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower())),
    Builders<Book>.Filter.Where(p => p.Description.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()))
            );
List<Book> books = Collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```